# How can I tell if a variable was exported or not in zsh (or bash)?

Tags: bash, variables, environment-variables, zsh

On the terminal how can I **easily** distinguish between

1. a shell variable: `foo=foovalue`

and

2. an exported environment variable: `export bar=barvalue`, **usable by child processes** ?

I know of `set` and `env` commands.  `set` reports both cases, without indicating which is which.  `env` does not report 1).

##### Sample terminal session

(on zsh + macos but that shouldn't matter overmuch):

```
$foo=foovalue           
$export bar=barvalue    

$set | egrep "^foo|^bar"
bar=barvalue
foo=foovalue

$env | egrep "^foo|^bar"
bar=barvalue
```

Any way to see both `foo` and `bar`, but also indicate that `foo` is a bash-only variable that will NOT be visible to child processes like a Python or Ruby script?  Typically, when my scripts don't see what I expect, what I end up doing is grepping my shell scripts and looking for where the variable was defined.  It works, but it's clunky at best.

Comment: `declare -p foo bar`, and see if the output says `declare --` or `declare -x`

Comment: If you want the variable export it, then `export foo`, and you know that it's exported. If you don't wan tit exported, `export -n foo` and then you know.

Comment: ...there's also a bash 5.0 feature that'll let you retrieve the flags; which version of bash are you targeting?

Comment: (note that the feature I'm considering **is** bash-specific, and will not work on zsh; zsh is not bash, nor is it compatible with bash, and questions about zsh should not say "bash" anywhere in them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `declare -p` would be a great answer.  And, yes, it also worked in zsh - I just checked.  I know they are not the same, but they are "close enough most of the time", at least from a user, not sysadmin, perpspective and looking for zsh-only answers often comes up empty.  This isn't a sysadmin script, it's troubleshooting my environment variables in an interactive session.

Comment: The bash 5.0 feature I was considering whether to propose is `[[ ${foo@a} = *x* ]]` -- _does_ that work in zsh?

Comment: Interactive troubleshooting is off-topic here and belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: No, `[[ ${foo@a} = *x* ]]` choked in zsh.  `declare -p | egrep 'foo|bar'` gave me `export bar=barvalue typeset foo=foovalue` on 2 lines.  Which is just what I needed!  bash and zsh commands are on-topic here though and this just ends up reminding us that `declare -p` exists and complement `set` and `env`.

Comment: Tagging and titleing your zsh questions "bash" is a good way to ensure that there _continue_ to be few on-point search results for questions about zsh in the future; it perpetuates the problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I have now both tags.  Both bash and zsh folk can use it.

Comment: (...whereas tagging zsh questions "bash" annoys the bash community much the same way as tagging C++ questions C annoys the C community)

Comment: Yet another possibility: `printenv foo`. Since _printenv_  is an external command, doing it this way is even shell-agnostic.

Comment: @JLPeyret : Having both tags, bash and zsh, is a bad idea. What are you going to do if you get one splendid answer for bash, and another splendid one for zsh? Which of those will you accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `declare -p` and inspect the output. For example:

```
declare -- BASH="/bin/bash"
declare -x EDITOR="vim"
```

It's obvious which one is exported or not.

Comment: looks a bit different on zsh, as noted.  but that's A-OK, by me, I am not parsing the results, just evaluating them with my Mk I eyeballs.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable_name="some value"
export variable_name
```

Check if the variable was exported:

```
declare -p variable_name | grep -q 'declare -x'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "The variable was exported."
else
  echo "The variable was not exported."
fi
```

Comment: [Why is checking `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) -- better to run `if declare -p variable_name | grep -q 'declare -x'; then` and avoid the extra `[` step.

Comment: ...that said, the OP appears to actually be running zsh, not bash, for which `declare -p` can output `typeset` commands and won't match the `declare -x` pattern at all.

Comment: Also, consider `unexported_var='declare -x'` as a case the above code fails with.